# Обрезание изображения

Tags: php

У меня стоит задача, сделать обрезание фото средствами выделения области. Для выделения области я использую плагин `imgareaselect`. При выводе изображения в блок `div`, его разрешение меньше чем исходный размер.

Проблема в том, что координаты для обрезания которые я передаю на сервер они применяются к исходному фото и обрезается не в тех местах, где было выбрано в блоке `div`.

Я думаю это можно решить используя формулы, которая будет брать значения исходного фото(ширина\высота) и смещать координаты. Формулу придумать не могу. Помогите пожалуйста с решением данного вопроса.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.cropimage.php  вроде оно

Comment: Нет, это просто обрезание фото с указанием параметров, а мне нужна формула, которая может смещать координаты согласно новой ширине и высоте исходного фото. Т.е. выбрал на превью участок который нужно обрезать и формула сместила координаты обрезания согласно исходному изображению